# Repeat rows in dataframe for n target columns by adding n-1 target columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

Given the following dataframe, where A, B, C are the original input column and X, Y, Z are the target columns, I would like to repeat rows in my dataframe by adding new column for X and Y as Xi and Yi as follows.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'id': ['1'],
    'A' : ['a1'],
    'B' : ['b1'],
    'C' : ['c1'],
    'X' : ['x1'],
    'Y' : ['y1'],
    'Z' : ['z1']
})
---
   id   A   B   C   X   Y   Z
0   1   a1  b1  c1  x1  y1  z1
```

For this above df, I would like to create new df with following data.

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'id': ['1', '1', '1'],
    'A' : ['a1', 'a1', 'a1'],
    'B' : ['b1', 'b1', 'b1'],
    'C' : ['c1', 'c1', 'c1'],
    'Xi' : ['0', 'x1', 'x1'],
    'Yi' : ['0', '0', 'y1'],
    'X' : ['x1', '0', '0'],
    'Y' : ['0', 'y1', '0'],
    'Z' : ['0', '0', 'z1']
})
---
   id   A   B   C   Xi  Yi  X   Y   Z
0   1   a1  b1  c1  0   0   x1  0   0
1   1   a1  b1  c1  x1  0   0   y1  0
2   1   a1  b1  c1  x1  y1  0   0   z1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for duplicated rows to groups with length 3 and then by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and
[`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) set `0` values:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(3)].copy()

m1 = df.index.duplicated()
m2 = df.index.duplicated(keep='last')

df['Xi'] = df['X'].where(m1, 0)
df['Yi'] = df['Y'].mask(m2, 0)

df['X'] = df['X'].mask(m1, 0)
df['Y'] = df['Y'].where(m1 & m2, 0)
df['Z'] = df['Z'].mask(m2, 0)


cols = df.columns[:4].tolist() + ['Xi','Yi'] + df.columns[4:7].tolist() 
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).reindex(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
  id   A   B   C  Xi  Yi   X   Y   Z
0  1  a1  b1  c1   0   0  x1   0   0
1  1  a1  b1  c1  x1   0   0  y1   0
2  1  a1  b1  c1  x1  y1   0   0  z1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.triu` and `numpy.diag` to generate appropriate boolean masks. The rest is only simple pandas masking:

```
df2 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(3)].copy()

mask1 = np.tile(np.triu(np.ones((3,2), dtype=bool)), (len(df), 1))
mask2 = np.tile(~np.diag(np.ones(3, dtype=bool)), (len(df), 1))

df2[['Xi', 'Yi']] = df2[['X', 'Y']].mask(mask1, 0)
df2[['X', 'Y', 'Z']] = df2[['X', 'Y', 'Z']].mask(mask2, 0)

df2 = df2[['id', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'Xi', 'Yi', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']]
```

*NB. the solution works for an arbitrary number of rows. If you always have a single row, you can remove the `numpy.tile` parts.*

output:

```
  id   A   B   C  Xi  Yi   X   Y   Z
0  1  a1  b1  c1   0   0  x1   0   0
0  1  a1  b1  c1  x1   0   0  y1   0
0  1  a1  b1  c1  x1  y1   0   0  z1
```